# Find the negation of $p(x)$ and $¬q(x)$, $\exists x\in X$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Find the negation of $p(x)$ and $¬q(x)$,  $\exists x\in X$

Is the answer $¬p(x)$ or $q(x)$?

Comment: Are you looking for the negation of $\exists x\in X[p(x)\wedge \neg q(x)]$? If not then why is the existential quantifier mentioned in your question? If yes then the negation is $\forall x\in X[\neg p(x)\vee q(x)]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $$\lnot(\exists x: (p(x) \land \lnot q(x))$$ is what you mean, then the answer by standard rules of first order logic equals

$$\forall x \lnot( p(x) \land \lnot q(x) )$$

which after de Morgan and double negation cancelling, becomes

$$ \forall x (\lnot p(x) \lor q(x))$$

Don't forget the quantifiers..